# Understanding the rough guess of an elliptic function of order 2

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-functions

So the first guess of the simplest elliptic function (of order 2) associated to the lattice
$L:=\mathbb Z+i\mathbb Z$ would be $$\sum_{m,n\in\mathbb Z}\frac{1}{(z-m-in)^2}$$
This sum is doubly periodic. But it is not considered to be an elliptic function since
is it not absolutely convergent at the point of $L$. But I don't understand why do we require this
while we we want the series to be unbounded in $L$ as the elements of $L$ are the poles?

For example, $$\sum_{m,n\in\mathbb Z}\frac{1}{(z-m-in)^2}=\frac1{z^2}+\sum_{m,n\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}}\frac{1}{(z-m-in)^2}$$
so in fact when $z=0$ the second summand diverges. But why we don't say that $0$ is a pole of the series?

Comment: The problem is that the series does not converge absolutely for points outside the lattice as well. You need to subtract something in every summand in order for the series to converge in $\mathbb{C} \backslash L$. What you end up with is called the Weierstraß $\wp$-function.